# Functions as private member variables in java

Tags: java, function, object, dynamic, private-members

I'm designing a type of Monopoly game to practice my Java skills.

I want there to be a "Space" class to represent a space on the game board. Something like this.

```
public class Space{

    private Player [] occupants;
    private String name;

    public Space(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

I am coming from a python background, so if I were doing it that way, I would probably initialize each space with some sort of "action" function, unique to each path. So Something like this.

```
class Space():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.action = None

GO_SPACE = Space()
def GO_ACTION():
    ## do some processing
GO_SPACE.action = GO_ACTION
```

Essentially assigning functions at run time to the Space object. I can't remember if I got the syntax just right, but hopefully it is clear what I am trying to do. Each space has its own unique function to process the actions when a player lands on it.

I am still open to changing the architectural direction of things, but how would I do something like this in Java? I admit, my knowledge of Java is a bit rusty, but my first thought was to try and assign a private member variable a function somehow... Is this approach way off? I can't remember if Java has functions as objects or anything like it.

Comment: Java 8 adds lambdas.

Comment: Thanks! Had no idea. I'll check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you need this to be dynamic. Why not something like this:

```
public abstract class Space {
    // name etc.
    public abstract void action(); 
}

public class GoSpace extends Space {
    public void action() { 
       // collect 200 dollars
    }
}
```

etc.

Comment: That is an interesting idea.. so basically have each space extend the Space class? I like this approach. Would there be any negative downsides to having so many subclasses (I'm thinking 40, or however many spaces are on the board)? If no, I think I will go with this and accept this answer.

Comment: I would create property files for each tile instead of a class for each.

Comment: Never heard of that.. is it a json/initialization type thing?

Comment: @Zack: No, it's common in java to have *lots* of classes. Class is a basic unit in java, *everything* is a class. Also note, I am not sure you really need 40 of them, because most of those 40 spaces on the board do not have any special action. You can make the base class non-abstract, and use it to represent those "plain" spaces. You might also consider making the special subclasses inner to the base class if you want to work around the stupid java rule of "one public class per file" ... or make them non-public if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Even with Java 8, the best approximation of function in Java is a single-method interface. For example, you can declare your `action` as [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and invoke it as `action.run()`

Comment: Sweet, I'll check this out as well. I mostly wanted to get some different perspectives, to help me think outside my python mindset. Thanks!